# "Please specify npm or yarn package" in PhpStorm/WebStorm when trying to install a new NPM package

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, npm, phpstorm, webstorm

Trying to add a new package I get the error below:

[image]

Going over settings everything looks good:

[image]
[image]

Any suggestions where to look next?

Comment: Click on `...` next to Node interpreter --- path to npm/yarn can be specified there. So far it looks like IDE is unable to detect it automatically for whatever reason.

Comment: same error aries me.

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 17):

You need to specify the path to npm.

go to settings->Languages and Frameworks->Node.js and NPM and click on the **...** alongside Node interpreter and then click on **...** beside npm package and give the path to npm, in my case it is `/usr/lib/nodejs/npm`.

[image]

Comment: and for RubyMine ? I don't have "Node.js and NPM" menu

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem happened when I try to install JavaScript library in idea from Linux. I solved this in idea by

1. install `Nodejs` plugin, then `Node.js and NPM` settings can be showed under `Languages & Frameworks`
2. under `Node.js and NPM` settings, in `node interpreter` item click `...`, set `npm package:` to `/usr/share/npm`

After then, I can download third-party JavaScript libraries.